# Find a formula for c(n, n − 2).

Tags: combinatorics, permutation-cycles

x[image]

I understand the answer that we can choose the 3 cycle in nC3 ways, but why is there 2 ways to do this? Hence times 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If i j and k are the chosen elements moved by the cycle, then (ijk) and (ikj) are both 3 cycles on these letters which are different, and there are no others.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say the $3$ elements in the $3$ cycle are $a,b,c$ then there are $6$ was to permute these but each perm will be equal to $2$ others
\begin{eqnarray*}
(abc)=(bca)=(cab) \\
(acb)=(cba)=(bac).
\end{eqnarray*}
$2$ ways !